# Moving keyframes by 30

Tags: keyframes

I'm trying to move a set of keyframes by 30.  If you see in the photo the first one is at 0 and 30 and line up correctly with a space of 30.  I then try to move it to 10 so the next keyframe would end at 40.  However, it seems to end at 39.  Is there a reason for this?  Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Comment: wasn't working on my computer.  do you have any advice for my keyframe issue?

Comment: You assumed that on the first image the key frames are on 0 and 30. They are actually on 1 an 30. By default the first (or Start) frame of the playback range is always frame 1, not frame zero. On the right side of the Header of the Timeline window you can see 3 values. The firsts is the active or selected frame, Next to that there are the Start and the End frame vlaues.

Answer (score 0):

First keyframe is **1**, not 0.

Make frame #1 your start one and then you have 30 frames like <1, 30>. Move start to #10 and it ends at frame #40.